# How can you render new JSX inside a life cycle method?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When my new state is mapped to my props I want to conditionally render a new JSX element like this

```
async componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: props) {
 if (nextProps.selectedStatement) {
  if (this.statementIsFiltered()) {
    return <Redirect to={location}/>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on render.

```
render() {

  if (this.props.selectedStatement && this.statementIsFiltered()) return <Redirect to={location} />

  return (
    <div>
      Rest of your code
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the way to go. `react-router` v4?

Try

```
async componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: props) {
 if (nextProps.selectedStatement) {
  if (this.statementIsFiltered()) {
    this.props.history.push(location)
 }
}
```

enhancing your component with `withRouter(YourComponent)`